# Commits github API

Tags: javascript, json, git, api, github

I'm interested to get ALL the commits done from my github page. I know for a fact that I can get the number a year back from github but, is there anyway to get all the commits done ever and retrieve it as a json file? So now it works from April 2013 - April 2014, but after this month I will get May 2013 - May 2014, is there anyway to get older commits also?

A solution can be that I set a timer when the code retreives data from a JSON file, saves the number in an array and then scrape the array with githubs JSON file?

Is there a better way or is it even possible to retreive data from longer than a year ago in the github API?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved by looking in a repo.

var uri = "https://api.github.com/repos/YOURUSERNAME/THEREPO/stats/contributors?client_id=xxxxxxxx";